# Defining multiple values inside a Scala Method

Tags: scala

I am very new to the Scala programming and while practicing Scala functions I wrote this without any error:

```
def house (facade:Double, window:Double): Double = {
val Door = 2x1
facade - Door -2 x window
} 
house(10,3)
```

But whenever I try to add another value (subArea) inside the method, it gives the error at 2*window:

```
 Found:    Unit
Required: Doublemdoc:
```

```
def House (facade:Double, window:Double): Double = val Door = 1x2    val subArea=facade - Door -2 x window}
```

Please Help.
thanks

Comment: I fixed your tags (you used bold `**` for code highlighting instead of 4 spaces indent/triple tickle, but the code was already wrong, so please fix it, as it is quite difficult to tell what you actually have there.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, the code which is giving you a compile error is something like:

```
def House(facade: Double, window: Double): Double = {
  val Door = 1 * 2
  val subArea = facade - Door - 2 * window
}
```

In a method body, the last expression will be the value that is returned. The last line in your method body is an assignment statement. Assignment statements have the type `Unit`, but the compiler is expecting to return a value of type `Double`. If you wish to return the value of `subArea`, make it the last expression in the method body:

```
def House(facade: Double, window: Double): Double = {
  val Door = 1 * 2
  val subArea = facade - Door - 2 * window
  subArea
}
```

You could also skip the `subArea` assignment altogether:

```
def House(facade: Double, window: Double): Double = {
  val Door = 1 * 2
  facade - Door - 2 * window
}
```

Comment: Yes it worked finally.
Thanks a lot :D

Comment: If this solved your issue consider accepting the answer unless you are not satisfied.